# how to detect event touch in subview or how to make parent view was touched when we touch subview?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, subview

I have 2 UIView.

the first one is a parent view

the second one is a subview,

how can we detect when a subview was touched?

or I want to make parent view was touched when user touch subview, any code can help me to do it? is it possible to do this?

because I have a Something Function, that will call when one of them was touched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has been solved. I think someone gave a great answer but I forget how.

This is what I did. There is an option in XIB. There is a checkbox (titled "User interaction enabled") that specifies whether a subview handle user event or not.

Uncheck that checkboxes and all touch to the subview goes to the parent view or whatever other view behind it.

Comment: And what's the name of that checkbox?

Comment: I nolonger code for iPhone and I have forgotten. I think it's the main difference between UIControl and UIView. UIControl has that checkboxes turned on by default.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

(Link the subview in xib or storyboard)

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *subview;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize subview;
@synthesize tapRecognizer;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                            action:@selector(handleTap:)];   

    [subview addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}

- (IBAction)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        //code here
        NSLog(@"subview touched");
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: In the handleTap function, I added the following line to hide the keyboard.

    [self.view endEditing:YES];

Answer (score 3):

to detect touch event you need to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` in your sub view or super view (in which you want get touch).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                    action:@selector(tap:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];


    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

then you can add delegate methods of `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
     // here you can get your touch
     NSLog(@"Touched view  %@",[touch.view class] );
}
```

hope it gives you idea..

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
UITouch *touch = [event.allTouches anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:YOUR VIEW NAME];
```